# Focus inside a select with javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-ce

The following code works fine in most browsers but it won't work in Internet Explorer CE Mobil and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

```
function autofocus() {
    var el = document.getElementById("autofocus");
    if (el === null) {
        return;
    } else if (el.tagName.toUpperCase() == "SELECT") {
        if (el.selectedIndex == -1) {
            el.options[0].selected = true;

        }
    }
    el.focus();
}

$(window).ready(function () {
    autofocus();  
});​
```

It works perfectly in all the regular browsers I have tried but in Internet Explorer Mobile it seems to focus on the select list itself which means it's not possible to navigate the various options without clicking one. Maybe if I click one of the options instead?. See http://jsfiddle.net/mhenrixon/sbwCv/19/ for an example of what is not working.

**EDIT:** It does not have to do with the selectedIndex per se since most of the time there will be a selectedIndex like 15, 5, 27 or whatever. Just not -1.

Comment: Try el.options[0].selected = 'selected;

Comment: already tried that before and no dice.

Comment: JavaScript on IE/CE is a strange beast. I remember giving up an going with NetFront because the JS implementation, although lacking, was better than IE.

Comment: Surely there must be some way though because clicking on an option focuses in the right place.

Comment: Is it actually calling el.focus()?  i.e., are the conditionals working  as expected?

Comment: @ToddMurray yes they are, tested and verified but the focus does not seem to "enter" the select and pick an option with anything less than a click. It's  a multiselect btw.

Comment: Have you tried to fire a click event yourself?  document.getElementById('autofocus').click();

Comment: Just tried it an alas it does nothing really. I tried clicking the option since I figured that was needed but the option has no click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Samsung Saga, I'm running:

*Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows CE; IEMobile 7.11) VZW:SCH-i770 PPC 320x320*

and the problem on this browser is the jQuery `ready` function.

If instead you use `<body onload="autofocus()">` the `<select>` will have its first option selected. And that option is indeed focused; if I use the optical mouse, I can right-arrow to a different option and space-bar to select it.

So here's the test case I've ended up with:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<!-- script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js" -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function autofocus() {
    var el = document.getElementById("autofocus");
    if (el === null) {
        return;
    } else if (el.tagName.toUpperCase() == "SELECT") {
        if (el.selectedIndex == -1) {
            el.options[0].selected = true;
        }
    }
    el.focus();
}

/*
$(window).ready(function () {
    autofocus();  
});
*/
</script>
</head>
<body onload="autofocus()">
<select autofocus="autofocus" id="autofocus" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="0">0:17,00st</option>
    <option value="P11">P11:1918,00st</option>
    <option value="P12">P12:100,00st</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

And of course it works on desktop browsers as well.

Comment: I'll be damned!! If I remove jQuery from the project "it just works" and I am talking about the reference to jQuery.js itself. Removed all references to jQuery and this started working perfectly! I would have NEVER thought of that. I actually had body onload autofocus(); already but jquery messed everything up on this particular setup. If you could answer that I'd give you another 50 :)

Comment: Glad I was able to power up that old device and give you an answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try if `el.selectedIndex = 2;` works or not, i can't seem to reproduce this problem in IE8, so may be the problem is just related to IE CE Mobile

```
function autofocus() {
    var el = document.getElementById("autofocus");
    if (el === null) {
        return;
    } else if (el.tagName.toUpperCase() == "SELECT") {
        if (el.selectedIndex == -1) {
            el.selectedIndex = 0;
            el.options[0].selected = true;
        }
    }
    el.focus();
}

$(window).ready(function () {
    autofocus();  
});
```

Comment: good catch, unfortunately it's unrelated since I mostly have a selectedIndex already. Sorry if that was not clear in the question.